# send all messages to a specific channel in discord js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I started coding my discord bot, and have just tried adding a feature that logs specific raw events to a specific channel. I looked countless times on Reddit and this site to try and find a way that isn't deprecated, but no luck. I was hoping that I would answer on this website. To summarize, I need to send messages to a specific channel. Another thing is pulling information from things inside JSON files that look like this:

```
info.json:  {t: 'PRESCENCE_UPDATE,
{other_thing_i_want_to_get: 'blah blah blah'}}
```

how do I get the other thing with a format of info.t.other_thing_i_want_to_get, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend creating a json file and importing it.

using the npm module [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) you can create WriteFileStreams to change the values stored in the file

```
const info = require('./path_to_json/info.json');
```

your json will have to look like:

```
{t: 'PRESCENCE_UPDATE', other_thing_i_want_to_get: 'blah blah blah'}
```

with this code you can get it using info.other_thing_i_want_to_get